# How to run and stop multiple Intervels in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, intervals

Suppose i am calling 3 interval with time 500ms,1s,1.5s.   once i click on 500ms button that time i need to stop other 2 interval run only 500ms. Like i click on 1s then stop previous interval that is 500ms. How i figure it out.

```
socket.on("interval-1",(value)=>{
        console.log(value);
        if(value==1){
           
            var timer1  = setInterval(function(){
                let price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                socket.emit("price",price)
               
            },500);
            
        }
        
        else if(value==2){
           
           var timer2  = setInterval(function(){
                clearInterval(timer1)
                let price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                socket.emit("price",price)
                
            },1000);
        }
        else if(value==3){
          
            setInterval(function(){
                clearInterval(timer1)
                clearInterval(timer2)
                let price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                socket.emit("price",price)
                
            },1500);
        }
        
    })
```

I tried it but once i interval it started it is not stoping when i click on run other intervals.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: you need to declare `timer1` and `timer2` as global variable, so when `value = 3`, `clearInterval` can access them.

Comment: @Layhout - Well, not as globals, but at the top level of the module.  The scope above the `scoket.on()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `timer1` and `timer2` variables are local to one execution of the `socket.on()` handle so when a subsequent handler comes, you can't access the previous variables.  You can fix this by declaring the timer variables at a higher scope so the same variable is accessible on subsequent socket.io messages.  I'd suggest an implementation like this:

```
let previousTimer;

socket.on("interval-1", (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    // clear any previous interval timer so it doesn't keep going forever
    if (previousTimer) {
        clearInterval(previousTimer);
        previousTimer = null;
    }
    if (value == 1) {
        previousTimer = setInterval(function () {
            let price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            socket.emit("price", price)
        }, 500);
    } else if (value == 2) {
        previousTimer = setInterval(function () {
            let price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            socket.emit("price", price)
        }, 1000);
    } else if (value == 3) {
        previousTimer = setInterval(function () {
            let price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            socket.emit("price", price)
        }, 1500);
    }
});
```

**Notes:** The variable I declared called `previousTimer` in this implementation is a module-level variable, not a global variable.  It is accessible only to the code within this module.

Also, you should stop using `var`.  Modern Javascript should use `let` or `const`, not `var`.

You also generally want to use `===` for comparisons, not `==`.  If the `value` variable is actually a number, not a string, then you should use `===` to compare it.  The comparison with `==` will attempt to do type conversion, allowing a number to be equal to a string which can lead to very unpredictable results in your code.